# What is the core memory structure in Python?

Tags: python

***How is data stored in the memory at the very last level?***

I am wondering about a thing that how memory is stored in Python at the least?
For example, if we make a link list or array, how will the data be stored? IS this the RAM or the Hard Disk? I am new to computer Science and this area of"Memory" is confusing.

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-memory-management/

Comment: Almost all programming languages work similarly. Variables are stored in RAM, files are stored on hard disk.